# How can I put some padding in between lines of text in a single Text() composable?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Whenever I increase the font size and bolden text in a single Text composable, if some of the text moves to the next line, the text on different lines touch. How can I pad the text?

Case in point, the S and the U in the image below touch each other.
[image]

Comment: Try increase the layout height and also the lineHeight of the textarea. That should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I ended up modifying the lineHeight property on the Text composable. A line height of about 30.sp was satisfactory for me. I don't know how this will fare on other screen sizes but its a good place to look if you end up with the same problem.

[image]